# problema con un timer

Tags: c#, timer

tengo una duda con mi timer, cuando lo inicio con un boton ejecuta mi funcion como se lo pido pero el problema viene cuando lo trato de detener con el metodo timer.stop(), ya que se sigue ejecutando en la seccion del timer.elapsed, aqui el codigo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya lo intente con
timer.dispose(), timer.stop(), timer.Enabled = false

Comment: actualicé la respuesta, respuesta, simplemente evita crear varias instancias del timer,saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define tu variable timer a nivel de clase para que no estes creando otra instancia al iniciar/detener el timer. De esta forma al cambiar el valor de flag al llamar el método nuevamente,  podras detener/iniciar el timer sin problema.

```
  //Define variable timer.
  private System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalMilliseconds);

    //Metodo para iniciar/detener el timer
    private void btnControlaTimer()
    {            
        if (flag == true) {
            Trace.WriteLine("entra a flag == true");
            timer.Elapsed += async (sender, ea) =>
          {
              prueba();
          };
           timer.Start();
           flag = false;                
        }
        else
        {
            timer.Stop();
            flag = true;
         }

    }
```

Incluso para que no se repita el llamado a "prueba()" , debes inicializar en otro lugar timer.Elapsed, ejemplo:

```
private bool flag = true;
private System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalMilliseconds);

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    timer.Elapsed += async (sender, ea) =>
    {
        prueba();
    };
}

private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    if (flag == true) {
      /*timer.Elapsed += async (sender, ea) =>
      {
          prueba();
      };*/
       timer.Start();
       flag = false;                
    }
    else
    {
        timer.Stop();
        flag = true;
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sería útil saber quién y cómo se está llamando al código que aparece en la imagen, con el contexto actual es complicado entender que pasa.

Lo que veo a primera vista es que estás creando una nueva instancia del timer cada vez que se ejecuta ese código, así que cuando hace el `timer.Stop()` está usando una instancia distinta a la que le añadiste el evento con `timer.Elapsed`. Es decir, estás parando otro timer. Deberías de instanciar el timer en un scope superior que pueda ser reusado. Por ejemplo:

```
public class Test
{
     private readonly Timer timer = new Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalMilliseconds);
     private bool flag = true;

     public void BotonPulsado()
     {
         if (flag)
         {
             timer.Start();
             flag = false;
         }
         else
         {
             timer.Stop();
             flag = true;
         }         
     }     
}
```